# confusion on subnet total addresses

Tags: ip-address, subnet

I know how to get a first and last usable, broadcast and network addresses
but my question is on total addresses,

for example if I have a address 146.88.57.23/25

would it be ---> 255 - 128 = 127 + 1  = 128

would that equal to 128 of total addresses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while i haven't played with ip addresses, but if i'm right and If it's ipv4, it would be 2^7=128, so you should be right ! (7=32-25 the number of bits left for the total adresses)